# Where should I initialize my variables?

Tags: java, oop, variables, conventions, coding-style

Is there any difference between initializing a variable inside and outside the constructor?
Which approach is better? Why?

```java
public class A {
  private List<Integer> myList;
  public A() {
    myList = new ArrayList<>();
  }
}
```

vs.

```
public class A {
  private List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
  public A() {
  }
}
```

Comment: Daily once , I see this question :)

Comment: Both won't compile. But if made to compile, there is no difference between them.

Comment: Extending Rohit's comment :`Collections won't work with primitives.`